What is the correct way to enable syntax highlighting for the Zig language?
Currently code blocks in questions tagged with zig (for Zig) do not get any syntax highlighting by default.
Adding lang-zig to the opening triple backticks of the code block seems to enable some syntax highlighting (e.g. at least comments are visible as such), but

it seems to not work reliably (sometimes after reloading the page the highlighting is gone),
the highlighting does not seem consistent (same elements of the language are sometimes highlighted differently in different parts of the code).

It makes me wonder whether lang-zig is meant to be used for the Zig language at all, and if so, why it isn't applied by default, or otherwise, what else would be the intended solution.

lang-zig is not a supported language code on Stack Exchange. If it's already supported by highlight.js you can make a feature-request here on MSO (or MSE) to request for it added to the supported language codes available on Stack Exchange. If highlight.js does not support the language then you'd need to make a feature request on their end to get it added and then after it's implemented create a feature-request here to have Stack Exchange include it.

With regard to the unreliability of adding lang-zig to a code block, you're experiencing the behaviour of using an unrecognised language identifier: "Any language identifiers used in a post that go unrecognized, are for languages that are not deployed on Stack Exchange, or are for tags that do not have a language hint specified in their data will be ignored and will trigger an automatic language detection." (also from the primary FAQ on MSE)

highlight.js supported languages: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md .  Zig is in there but is an extension, so SO would need to specifically activate it.
